# Why do I randomly start with a shield sometimes?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

Sometimes I randomly start with a shield when I'm playing local multiplayer. What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a result of autobalancing in versus mode.

- **Player(s) behind by 3 or more points**: Start round with a shield
- **Player(s) with the most points**: Start round with fewer arrows

Autobalancing can be toggled on or off in the Variants menu.

[image: Variants menu]

Answer (score 2):

Shields are given to players who are low on points in versus mode. Similar effects such as changing the arrow count on losing and winning players works the same way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not doing so well"? What causes it to appear? Number of kills the other player has, number of deaths you have, etc

Comment: It's rubber-banding. Like. Give a handicap to the player that is ahead by many points. To even up the game a bit. Throw the losing player a bone. And so on.